# "EggSMClient-WARNING **: Failed to connect to the session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported"

Tags: sudo, gedit

I am on ubuntu 12.10.

Every time that I try to open gedit on root this appears:

```
(gedit:3254): EggSMClient-WARNING **: Failed to connect to the session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported

** (gedit:3254): WARNING **: Could not connect to session bus
```

Comment: Is it just a warning, or a fatal error preventing you from running gedit? (regardless, `gksudo` is the way to go)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`gksudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo) for this:

```
gksudo gedit
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: `bash: gksudo: command not found`

Answer (score -4):

I had the same issue. Resolved with the following command

```
sudo gedit &
```

Comment: Note that the messages shown in the Terminal are not really a problem, and all running gedit with & after it does is to suppress those messages. The underlying (extremely minor) issue that produces the messages is not fixed by doing that. @guntbert `sudo gedit` might [make `gedit` not work when run as the non-root user](http://askubuntu.com/q/270006/22949). We we've discussed, I think it's not very likely to lock out local GUI logins, **but I am not 100% sure**. It [might or might not](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=login+loop+is%3Aquestion) be the practical cause of such problems.

Comment: -1 Ugh, detaching `sudo` from the shell is a terrible idea.