# Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?

Tags: sudo, gui, gksu

I've read [the comunity "RootSudo" documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) and am interested in this line:

> You should **never** use normal sudo to start graphical applications as Root.

Why? What is the difference? Please provide a simple explanation, as I'm just a normal desktop user.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between “gksudo nautilus” and “sudo nautilus”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus)

Comment: Actually, I recently had a hard time installing MATLAB to /usr/local. This required root privileges to write to /usr/local, but running the installer using gksu somehow made it impossible to run the installed program as non-root. Running the installer using sudo made everything work just fine.

Comment: Another reason: [any application (even without root privileges) can sniff keyboard input](https://superuser.com/questions/301646/linux-keylogger-without-root-or-sudo-is-it-real) and get your sudo password. A graphical sudo might try to prevent that.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

> In Ubuntu 19.10 and later, the admonition in [that article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo) (and in this answer) no longer applies. See [WinEunuuchs2Unix's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1047413/22949) as well as [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186999/how-does-sudo-handle-home-differently-since-19-10).

Graphical applications often store settings and other user-specific data in configuration files written inside the user's [home folder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory). The main mechanism applications use to determine what they should use as the user's home folder is the `HOME` [environment variable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables). (You can inspect it yourself with `echo $HOME`).

Suppose you're running [`gedit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/gedit.1) (a graphical text editor) as [`root`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_user#Unix_and_Unix-like). If you run `sudo gedit`, `HOME` will continue to point toward *your* home directory, even though the program is running *as `root`*. Consequently, `gedit` will write configuration files *as `root`* into your home directory. This [will sometimes result](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632798/what-specific-bad-things-happen-when-gedit-is-used-with-sudo) in the configuration files being *[owned](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) by `root`* and thus [*inaccessible to you*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150028/you-are-not-the-owner-message-when-trying-to-access-folder) (when you later run the program as yourself and not as `root`). This mainly happens when the application has to create a new configuration file. Newly created files, by default, are owned by the user who creates them (who in this case is `root`, not you).

That's the primary reason why you should run graphical applications with a graphical `sudo` frontend rather than with straight `sudo`. In Ubuntu and most of its derivatives (including Xubuntu and Lubuntu), the standard graphical frontend is [`gksu`/`gksudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/gksu.1). In Kubuntu it is [`kdesudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/kdesudo.1). (It depends on the [desktop environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment#Desktop_environments_for_the_X_Window_System) being used.)

If you *want* to use `sudo` directly to run a graphical application like `gedit`, you can run:

```
sudo -H gedit
```

The `-H` flag makes `sudo` set `HOME` to point to `root`'s home folder (which is [`/root`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//root)).

That still won't automatically handle the ownership of [`.Xauthority`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_authorization#Cookie-based_access) by copying it to a temp folder (this is the other thing that graphical `sudo` frontends take care of for you). But in the infrequent event that `.Xauthority` is inaccessible, you'll get an error saying it is, and then you can fix the problem by deleting it (`sudo rm ~/.Xauthority`), as it's automatically regenerated. Thus, protecting `.Xauthority`'s ownership and permissions is less important than protecting the ownership and permissions of configuration files.

In contrast to a `root`-owned `.Xauthority`, when configuration files become owned as `root`, it's not always as obvious what the problem is (because graphical programs will often run, but not work very well, and output any useful errors to the console). And it's sometimes a bigger hassle to fix, especially *if you're in a situation where you want one or more files in your home directory to be owned by someone other than you* (because then you cannot fix it simply by recursively `chown`ing all your files back to yourself).

Therefore, `sudo` (at least without `-H`) should not be used to run a graphical application *unless* you are highly familiar with the app's inner workings and know for sure that it does not ever attempt to write any configuration files.

Comment: Can I become the owner of all configuration files (or any files) on my Home directory again, if these file has been owned by root?

Comment: @Nur Assuming there are *no* files in your home directory that you *want* to be owned by any other user *or that you want to have any other group membership (for sharing)*, you can run: `sudo chmod -R $USER:$USER ~` Unfortunately, those criteria don't always apply. If you have any files where you need to preserve the group owner, you can run `sudo chmod -R $USER ~`. This is usually sufficient. (If you have files need to be owned by another user in your home directory, even that will be a problem.)

Comment: @Nur If you haven't had any errors or problems, then even if you've been running graphical applications as root with straight `sudo`, it's possible that you've been fortunate enough that you don't have any root-owned configuration files. (This could happen if it never had to create a file, which is the main circumstance where a file becomes owned by root.) If you haven't had any problems, I wouldn't worry.

Comment: @EliahKagan Does `chmod` actually do it? I always thought it was `chown` that did it. `chmod` never did it for me.

Comment: @Wyatt8740 I should definitely have written `chown` instead of `chmod` in my comments above. Sorry about that -- and thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: So gksudo will care for me of the owner problem? Or do I still keep these considerations in mind when using gksudo?

Comment: @Zaibis Yes, with `gksudo` you don't have to worry about this. When you use `gksudo` or `kdesudo` to run a GUI program, you won't get unexpected root-owned files in your home directory. That's why they're ideal. You also get a graphical password prompt, so you can use them from a run dialog (Alt+F2) as well as a terminal. The reason I mention `sudo -H` is only some Ubuntu flavors have `gksudo` or `kdesudo` preinstalled anymore. You can still install `gksudo`. (`kdesudo` is only for a system with KDE.) But if you don't want to, `sudo -H` is a reasonable choice and *far* better than bare `sudo`.

Comment: Are there situations where gksudo should not be used? ...or any other reason why I should not create an alias for sudo to use gksudo even when I forget to?

Comment: @Superole This is a good question; for more depth, I suggest posting it. But yes, often `gksudo` shouldn't be used, and I don't recommend aliasing `sudo` to it. For non-GUI commands, you sometimes want to keep `$HOME`; `gksudo` requires a usable display (try `DISPLAY= gksudo ls` vs. with `sudo`); `sudo` and `gksudo` have different options and some of the "same" ones like `-k` are unrelated; and `gksudo` prompts for a password even if you just ran it successfully. Also you'd still need to be careful as [aliases aren't always expanded](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases).

Comment: gksu is not available any more in Debian 9 and Ubuntu 18.04 - see more at https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gksu and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/umit/+bug/1740618  Here is a question asking for alternatives: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042344/

Comment: Running `sudo -H echo $HOME` still returns my normal user's home and not the /root or /home/root directory (sudo version 1.8.21p2 on Linux Mint 19.1).

Comment: @TheQuark In `sudo -H echo $HOME`, your shell--running as you, not as root--performs [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) on `$HOME`, obtaining the path of *your* home directory, then passes that to `sudo`, which in turn passes the already-expanded value to `echo`, which prints it. `sudo -H printenv HOME`, `sudo -H bash -c 'echo $HOME'`, and `sudo -H sh -c 'echo $HOME'` all print `/root`. This is conceptually similar--though by a different mechanism--to how `x=a echo "$x"` doesn't print `a` (unless `x` already had the value `a`).

Comment: To keep everything out of home, I just use `sudo -i` instead.

Answer (score 28):

Simply put:

> This prevents files in your home directory becoming owned by root.

Read it [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/21038/58950). Also, possibly a duplicate of [What is the difference between "gksudo nautilus" and "sudo nautilus"?](https://askubuntu.com/q/11760/58950)

Comment: gksudo is not longer included with the Ubuntu and Debian installs. See https://itsfoss.com/gksu-replacement-ubuntu/ for details. https://askubuntu.com/a/1047413/197910 is now the superior solution.

Answer (score 15):

### Ubuntu 19.10 update

As of [Ubuntu 19.10](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2019-May/018345.html), typing `sudo some_command` now has the same effect as typing `sudo -H some_command`. This means the directory for any configuration files touched will be under `/root` directory and not `/home/regular_userID` directory (aka `$HOME`).

This makes this whole Q&A a moot point to a large degree for Ubuntu 19.10 users and greater.

To see whether `sudo` is working like `sudo -H` in your distribution try these short tests:

```
$ sudo printenv | grep HOME
HOME=/home/rick

$ sudo -H printenv | grep HOME
HOME=/root
```

As you can see, `sudo` above does not perform like `sudo -H` so using plain `sudo` can harm your user configuration files.

---

An alternative to `gksu nautilus`, `gksu gedit` or `sudo -H gedit` is to use the `nautilus-admin` add-on. It allows you to browse files and directories with **Nautilus** and then open them as root (Administrator).

Installation is straight forward:

```
sudo apt install nautilus-admin
```

Now when you are in Nautilus you'll have an extra option to Edit as administrator:

[image: nautilus admin.gif]

---

### `gedit` as root doesn't allow preferences

When you run `gedit` as root you can't use the preferences you've set up as a regular user for tab stops, convert tabs to spaces, font name, font size, line wrap, etc.

To solve this I've written the script `sgedit` to inherit user preferences and apply them to root: [How can I sync my root gedit with my user gedit's preferences?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92655/how-can-i-sync-my-root-gedit-with-my-user-gedits-preferences/1047405#1047405)

- Call using `sgedit filename1 filename2 ...`
- Gets user's gedit settings for tab stops, fonts, line-wrap, etc.
- Elevates to `sudo -H` to preserve file ownership whilst getting root powers.
- Requests password if last `sudo` has timed out.
- Gets sudo's gedit settings
- Compares differences between user and sudo gedit settings
- Runs gsettings set on the differences only (reduces 174 set commands to a dozen or less. Next time it's run perhaps only one or two changes but often times no changes.
- Calls `gedit` as a background task such that terminal prompt reappears immediately.

Comment: It is better not to run gedit as root at all, but use admin:///. That is actually what the  nautilus-admn extension does. With a dead simple wrapper script, you can do that also easily from the command line, see my anser to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1191075/how-to-open-a-text-file-in-current-working-directory-with-gedit-admin/1191093#1191093

Comment: Just to clarify:  does the above edit mean that in 19.10+ it is safe to run `sudo {GUI command}` now just like we would use `gksudo {GUI command}` before gksudo was removed?

Comment: @TrailRider Yes as the top voted answer here explains in detail.